# Tables representing an enumerated list of codes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I've looked through similar questions but I'm still a little perplexed about something that seems to be a simple case in Rails.

Let's say I have a model class called `Employee`. One attribute of an employee is their `security_clearance`, which is a string that can be `None`, `Some`, or `Full`. No other values are valid. In other applications I'd probably represent this an `Employees` table that has a foreign key to the `SecurityClearances` table, which has exactly three rows. The `SecurityClearances` table has columns entitled `code` (e.g. `SEC_CLEARANCE_NONE`, `SEC_CLEARANCE_SOME`, ...) and `value` ("None", "Some", "Full").

How do I want to do this in Rails? Do I want `has_one :security_clearance` on `Employee` and `belongs_to :employee` on `SecurityClearance`? That doesn't seem to be quite right.

It seems nonoptimal to type out the string literals of None, Some, and Full everywhere, especially since the values to be displayed could change (for example, perhaps the string for the `Some` code will be change to be `low clearance` instead).

---

#### Update:

Now that I think about this some more, don't I really just want a `belongs_to :security_clearance` on Employee? That would do the trick, right? Employees need to know what their security clearance levels are, but security clearance levels have no tie to a particular employee.

Comment: Your update is right. You don't need the has_many on the clearance levels class. 
Sooner or later, though, if you end up having to report all the people with a specific clearance, then you would need the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this plugin: http://github.com/mlightner/enumerations_mixin/tree/master

It allows you to define this like `has_enumerated :security_clearance`, besides also caching the SecurityClearance model, etc.

Without the plugin, though, you're right about the relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out the Enum Fields plugin from the GiraffeSoft folks:
http://giraffesoft.ca/blog/2009/02/17/floss-week-day-2-the-enum-field-rails-plugin.html